# Will Heathcare Services ever pick up if I stay on hold?

Tags: twelve-minutes

There is a point in *Twelve Minutes* where you can use a phone to call a Healthcare Provider. Calling will lead to you getting put on hold. After waiting for a bit, you are given an option to hang up or keep waiting.

Will someone from Healthcare Services eventually pick up if I wait on hold? Or is this number only callable as a joke?